# One domain for two separate Firebase projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two projects. Project A holds my static landing page, and project B holds my Angular app. Is it possible to use one domain name for both projects? Is that the correct approach? Or, can I host both the static landing page and the Angular app under the same project?

i.e., www.foo.com (Landing page), www.foo.com/bar (Angular app)

Comment: You can indeed host them under the same project. Your SPA redirect would be specific to the bar/ directory instead of root.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A single domain name can only be associated with a single Firebase project. There is no way to use the same domain name with two projects.

The closest you can get is by mapping a different subdomain to each project. E.g. `www.foo.com` for one and `bar.foo.com` for the other.

Comment: Thanks Frank! That was what I needed to do. My apologies for the late reply.